# Record with high volume in android

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I am doing audio recording using MediaRecorder, but unfortunately when I playback the recorded audio, I have media with a very low volume. I don't hear anything (almost anything).

Is there any possibility to increase recording volume? Like setVolume() when we record?
I try to see in MediaRecorder API but i can't find setVolume or something like that..
Is there any work around? 
Thanks.

Comment: r u using Emulator for testing or a real Device ? If you are using Realy Device then please check the MediaSound volume also.

Comment: I use real device.. So i have to change the media player volume to record with high volume?

Comment: @user430926: Yes Dear friend, iDroid Explorer is right. There is no facilities to record with different volume instead of the MediaVolume. So please accept it so it can help others. or put some more information or update your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well after some r&d and googling i found is there is no specific volume for mic. when you are recording that takes media volume as mic volume.

So to set it, Goto

```
Settings->Sound->Volume->
```

and check Media volume.

If you wan to Record in the full Volume then keep Media Volume high and if you want to record in low Volume then keep Media Volume Small.

AIK there is no other sollution.

So please do it for your case.

Comment: Is there any API to change the volume sound of the device?? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. and Well right now i dont have idea about the api to change the Sound.

Comment: Do Something like that. Copy that recorded file to any other device or pc and check it. So you will sure that is it recorded poperly or not. let me know what happens. Keep responces.

Comment: Maybe you missunderstand what i mean..
I want to make an app to record using MediaRecorder with certain volume set by user. I can recorded it but how to change the volume when I recording? Or is thera any post process that i have to do to make it happen? Thanks.

Comment: @user430926: I understand what you said. but may be its a fault of the device or anything else. So i have said to check it in other device. And if still the same problem then please put the code with which you are recording it.

Comment: Sometime it happens if the mice is not properly work so you can able to record it properly. So please check it with other device.

Comment: Ok now i got you properly. . . . wait till i update the answer.

Comment: i think there is no specific volume for mic. when you are recording that takes media volume as mic volume. Please see my updated answer. . . .

Comment: Yes, i have check it no specific volume for mic.. Can you suggest other solution?

Comment: I have updated the Answer. And as i know there is no another sollution for it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to take a media volume as mic volume for `asus zenfone`. Whether the media volume is low or high it records the audio in the same volume

Comment: @Arti I don't have try out with asus zenfone and its technology. Need to check it and will let you know later for same.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer Thanks for the quick response, awaiting your reply.