# Android MediaRecorder set audio volume

Tags: android, audio, sdk, volume, mediarecorder

I'm not that familiar with android programming and would like to set the audio volume while (or before) recording a video with `MediaRecorder`. Is there a way to do that? Or is there a better way to record a video with variable audio volume, instead of using `MediaRecorder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set volume while recording using `MediaRecorder`. But you can set volume while playing using `MediaPlayer` by using the method `setVolume(float, float)`

Comment: Well but there are audio recorders for android where it is able to set the recording volume. i was hoping that it would be possible to control it also while recording a video.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328366/record-with-high-volume-in-android check this reference.. i haven't found anything to set volume while recording

Comment: mh ok, but how are then apps like TapeMachine for example recording in different volumes? (in TapeMachine its called Gain) Are they using their own codecs or what?

Comment: if you want to add gain to audio recording you can try one thing. use audiorecord to record raw audio.. from there you can increase or decrease gain .. for example if you multiply the sample by some fraction the gain will be added. but i can not see any way to do this while video recording. you may record audio and video separately

Comment: Well seems that this would be the only possiblity. You dont know how to do that, do you?

Comment: i told in the previous comment. use mediarecorder to record video. set sound input off. at the same time record sound using audiorecord. and process sample data from audiorecord. this seems the only way but not sure about that. best of luck

Comment: Yes ok, but then i have to merge the audio and video file, right? Well anyways, thank you!

Comment: Ok seems that it isnt possible. If i run mediaRecorder alone (without audio) it works. If i run audioRecord alone it works. if i start both together, the app crashes. i wasnt able to figure out why, but it seems that both interfere with each other.